RemoveSession using thymsleaf
I have created a CommonServiceImpl, it is responsible for removal of session in spring boot project. But I get a Potential null pointer access error by getAoccur please help me get rid of this error.
@Service public class CommonServiceImpl implements CommonService { 
   HttpSession session=((HttpServletRequest)RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getSession();

   if (session != null) {
       // Remove the success and error message attributes from the session
       session.removeAttribute("succMsg");
       session.removeAttribute("errorMsg");
   }
}

The Potential null pointer access: The method getRequestAttributes() may return nullJava.
How can I rid of this issue?

Just check if the request object is null, and return early if it is.
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();

if (request == null) {
    return;
}

HttpSession session = request.getSession();

if (session != null) {
   // Remove the success and error message attributes from the session
   session.removeAttribute("succMsg");
   session.removeAttribute("errorMsg");
}


thank u for help i will
